# Google Analytics screen views and session are zero

Tags: google-analytics

I implemented Analytics in Android. And it's working, but screen views and sessions are zero. It's been more then 12 hours and everything else is tracked and I can see data except screen views and session

Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);//prikaz progres dialoga
    tracker = ((BornToInvestApplication) getApplication())
            .getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

//call MD5Hash class from Utils package and call md5 method for has android_id

    //set user id on google analitycs
    android_id= Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    // You only need to set User ID on a tracker once. By setting it on the tracker, the ID will be
    // sent with all subsequent hits.
  //  String dimensionValue = "SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE";
  // tracker.set(Fields.customDimension(1), dimensionValue);//we can't reconize Fields??????

//call method md5 form md object
    tracker.set("&uid", md.md5(android_id));
    tracker.set("&cd1", md.md5(android_id));

}

//tracking next story with GA in NewspageFragment

MainActivity.tracker.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                    .setCategory(AnalyticsEventsConsts.NEXT_STORY_EVENT)
                    .setAction(allnewsObj.get(pos).getTitle())
                    .setLabel(AnalyticsEventsConsts.STORY_PARAMETER)
                    .build());
```

Class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyClassApplication extends Application {

    // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.
    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXX-3"; // client
    private static  String android_id="";
    private DataManager dataManager;

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg:
        // roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a
        // company.
    }

    HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        dataManager = new DataManager(getApplicationContext());
        //call MD5Hash class for hash android_id
        MD5Hash md = new MD5Hash();
        android_id=Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    }


    //set GA tracker when stays in documentation of GA
    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics
                    .newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
                    : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics
                    .newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker) : analytics
                    .newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }

}
```

And here is data:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are sending just the events, so it's expected that you have no data for screen views.

To track the screen views you need to call the tracker, set the screen name and then send it.

It's something like this:

```js
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.
t.setScreenName(screenName);

// Send a screen view.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

For more information you can access the Google Developers Docs [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens)

Hope I've helped you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out and let you know. If it works, I'm gonna accept your answer :)

Comment: It's working now. Only sessions are not working [Look at screenshot](http://s16.postimg.org/p0riumyf9/Capture.png)

Comment: FosAvance, the events and screen views are now working but only the sessions aren't? I saw that the sessions were working at the first report you sent, did you changed something in the events? Sorry for the delay